# Javascript: I cannot seem to get values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the stuff earlier, i'm new here. So here is the part of the code i have a problem with. it says throwOuts is undefined, I've edited my jsfiddle to the stuff i added in but it still doesn't work unfortunately

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzuyw8cr/) to support my question, look at the Javascript:

```
p1_score =  parseInt(document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML);
    var p1_out = throwOuts[p1_score];
    console.log(p1_out);
    p1_score = p1_score* 1 - score* 1;
    if (p1_score >= 2)
    {
        if (p1_score <= 170)
        {
            document.getElementById("outs").innerHTML = p1_out;
            document.getElementById("player_1").innerHTML = p1_score;
            document.getElementById("score").value = "";
            player_switch()
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code here, there is a reason there is a warning in the post editor that warns about using JSFiddle links without posting code

Comment: Please include the [mcve] inside your post, not on an external link. SO also has a code snippet feature for HTML/CSS/JS examples.

Comment: I guess your code is working just that in js fiddle setting you need to wrap in body so that function is loaded before on click https://jsfiddle.net/hzuyw8cr/2/

Comment: AFAICT your `throwOuts` array is local to the `outs` function but you're trying to use it in the `calculate` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your JSFiddle, it becomes clear that `throwOuts` is only defined inside your `function outs(p1_score,p2_score)` function.

Move your code that declares `throwOuts` (`var throwOuts=[];`) out of the `outs` function, and it should work properly.

Also, some observations:

1. You don't seem to be modifying `throwOuts` anywhere. If this is the case, you might want to call `outs` only once, since you only need to initialize the array once.
2. In lines 17 (`if (p1_score <= 170)`) and 46 (`if (p2_score <= 170)`), the if block and else block do the exact same thing. Is this a typo?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's not a TYPO. As you may have seen it's something for darts. I made it for 2 players. 

The thought behind lines 17 and 46 are that you can finish the game once you have hit 170 points, so from that point I would like to set the html to the throw out possibilities. I did it 2 times because both players will have a different score so a different throw out

Thank you so much for helping me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What i ment is that the else block has the same code as the if block, and this happens in both at line 17 and 46

Comment: Oh in that way. Well I did that so the code will be executed no matter what. In the if block i will add some stuff when the points are under 170, and if it isnt under 170 points it still needs to be exucuted :)

Comment: @Sylent If you want to execute some code *no matter what*, then why do you feel the need for `if` statement ?

Comment: @Sylent exactly, if you want to execute the code no matter what, you don't need an if/else. Just execute the code without any condition.

Comment: I used the if statement because that part will decide if i need to change the innerhtml when the points hit <170 otherwise it would give a error because of my array which doesnt go higher then 170. hope i explained it good enough @Rafalon

Comment: @Sylent well I'm not sure I understood, but maybe you can put the code that changes if points < 170 or >= 170 in the `if` and move the code which is the same in both cases **outside** the `if`. It is usually good practice to avoid repeating code (search DRY - Don't Repeat Yourself)